# C++ Request a specific row from a file

Tags: c++, file, data-structures, file-handling

Is there a way, where I can open a file that contains a large amount of data, and retrieve only one specific row or index, without getting the rest of the content as well?

Update:

Based on what others have mentioned here in the comments, I have some follow-up questions.

Can anyone give me an example of how to put a fixed width on the rows/linebreaks(whatever you want to call it), or show me a good source where I can read more about it?

So if I set this up correctly, I will be able to get a specific line from the file superfast, even if it contains several million rows?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the file. Are all the rows the same length? You need to add more details.

Comment: If the lines have all the same size (on disk) it could be possible otherwise I do not think so.

Comment: files dont have rows (nor columns). They are just a stream of bits and bytes. Only if, as others already suggested, the rows have a fixed width you can jump to a certain position inside the file without reading character by character to see if there is a line break

Comment: @johnnymopp I Want to know how I can create this structure and what file I need to use in that case if its possible. Im open for any options. There is no data at the moment, im planning ahead

Comment: What structure are you talking about?  Is this a human readable format or binary?

Comment: Based on what others have mentioned here in the comments, I have some follow-up questions. I have updated my question. @Thomasmatthews how about both :)

Comment: When creating the file, use the `setw` to set the field width.  Also, make sure that the rows have the same quantity of fields.

Comment: If you plan on having data and accessing it, consider using an external database.  Search [softwarerecs.se] for database and interface libraries.  A lot better that you implementing tables in files and indexing tables, as well as the code to search and maintain the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a file by records or rows, and the rows are not fixed length, you'll have to create a structure that you can associate (or map) file positions to row indices.

I recommend using `std::vector<std::streampos>`.

Read through the file.
When the file is at the beginning of a row, read the file position and append to the vector.

If you need to access a row in the file:
1) Use the vector to get the file position of the row.
2) Seek to the row using the file position.

This technique will work with fixed length and variable length rows.

Comment: I dont want to read through the whole file. I Want to start at the right point

Comment: If you don't want to build a vector of file positions, then make the rows in the file fixed length.  You may want to consider writing out structures into a binary file.  Search the internet for "c++ serialization" or "c++ boost serialization".

Comment: Thanks. But how do I start scanning the file from that specific position, and skip everything before